# android menu button and action bar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I would like to build an app that work for android versions  2.3 and up , so i think to use the menu and don't use the the action bar because android lower than 4 doesn't has action bar.
But I know that there are some devices don't have menu button, so how the user could open the menu, if there is no menu button and also action bar.
please help me
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an ImageButton (with the three dots from the holo action bar) that opens the settings activity.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Android have support for ActionBar on devices with Android version lower than 4.0. Look at this tutorial of the support library AppCompat http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-how-to-use/

Comment: thank you for your response, actually I think that actionbarsherlock is more general, what do you think ?